# How to make a mask with blur effect?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to reproduce the following layout in React Native/Expo, I found the `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` that seemed, at first glance, to cover my needs.

I need to have a map (I'm using react-native-maps) and cover part of it with some blurry semi-transparent white view.

But I realized it doesn't properly support semi-transparent masks, because if I use them, any content I put on top of the blur area inherits the mask transparency as well, even if positioned outside the MAskedView component.

Also, it doesn't seem to support blurring the content behind the mask.

How can I reproduce this on React Native?

Below you can see a mockup to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: mockup]

Comment: Try using [React Native Skia](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/getting-started/installation)

Comment: @kartikey AFAIK Skia can only mask elements rendered within a Skia canvas.

Comment: Use Backdrop Blur from here https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/backdrops-filters

Comment: @ImanRoosta that still only applies to Skia-rendered content only

Comment: just trying to understand your question, you want part of your map blurred and want to add some content on top of blurred map but this content should not be blurred.

Comment: @RohitSK yes exactly, in the blurred area I will add some text and inputs.

Comment: hi any solution now, I found react-native-hole-view can do it but it's require x,y,w,h for hole params. I want to using child as hole

Comment: you can use a combination of react-native-maps, react-native-svg, and react-native-svg-filter packages.

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/blur

Comment: there is an issue with react-native-maps or blur so we can not blur the map in Android, [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4356) is link to that issue. Another way to add blur to maps is via SVG filters but react-native-svg does not support filters. I have tried using svg image with blur filter to add blur effect but that also does not seem to work.

Comment: @Gauravsinghrajpoot I cant find package named ```react-native-svg-filter```, can you please share link to it.

Answer (score 2):

I have nearly achieved what you needed. Nearly because [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) currently doesn't support filters and [@react-native-community/blur](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/blur) doesn't work with [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4356) as pointed out by [Rohit S K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12324247/rohit-s-k) in comments. We are using SVG shape. Just understand this [cubic cruves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#b%C3%A9zier_curves) from mozilla and you will be able to control it more as per your needs.
Here is the code of my `App.tsx` file

```js
    import React, {JSX} from 'react';
    import {SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
    
    import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
    import {BlurView} from '@react-native-community/blur';
    import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
    import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg';
    
    function App(): JSX.Element {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
          <StatusBar
            backgroundColor="rgba(245,245,245,0.3)"
            barStyle={'dark-content'}
          />
          <MapView
            style={styles.mapView}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          />
          <View style={styles.svgWrapper}>
            <Svg
              preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice"
              height="100%"
              width="100%"
              viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <Path
                d="M 0 85 C 20 60, 80 60, 100 85 L 100 0 0 0"
                fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
              />
              <Path
                d="M 0 85 C 20 60, 80 60, 100 85"
                stroke="rgba(221,221,221,1)"
                strokeWidth={0.5}
                fill="transparent"
              />
            </Svg>
            <BlurView
              style={styles.blurView}
              blurType="light"
              blurAmount={10}
              reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
            />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      safeArea: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
        height: '100%',
        position: 'relative',
      },
      mapView: {
        minHeight: '100%',
      },
      blurView: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      svgWrapper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '55%',
        aspectRatio: 1,
      },
    });
    export default App;
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

### Update

As pointed out by [Nikolas Charalambidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764965/nikolas-charalambidis), there's a flaw in this solution. The background isn't blurred, so it's an incomplete solution. I hope that someone comes up with a better solution or we wait for react-native-svg to support filters or @react-native-community/blur to work with maps.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not easy. Anyway I found a way which gets close to it:

```html
    <MapView
      style={styles.mapStyle}
      initialRegion={initRegion}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <BlurView intensity={50} style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill]}></BlurView>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
    </MapView>
```

This renders a map which is blurred in the upper half and clear in the lower half. Maybe if you play a little with styles, you can obtain what you want!